# More than one real input per transaction?

Tags: transaction-data, ringsize

Is it possible to have more than one real input in a monero transaction?

If yes, how can you know how many mixins are there and how many real inputs?

If no, how do you explain this: https://moneroblocks.info/search/db7523bd6d72b91eb841eb2815cb4dc0810191fec87d5e86a6c45e4a05671a44

It's written that it has 43 inputs, and that it has 5 mixins? What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, transactions can be composed of multiple real inputs. In that case, each input will be mixed with `n` 'fake' inputs (`n` is the number of other members in the ring, a.k.a mixin). The mixin level is the same for all inputs.
For instance, the transaction in the link you provided is composed of 43 real inputs, each one of them has been mixed with 5 fake inputs. This means that in the entire transaction 43*5=215 fake inputs were used (43*6=258 counting the real ones).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jona!

Is it possible to get the information what are the candidates (so 1 real and n fake) for every input in every transaction?

And was it always like this that a transaction can have more than one real input?

Comment: Choosing the ring members is not straightforward. Currently, some of the members are chosen from recent blocks, and the rest from older blocks using triangular distribution. This topic is being discussed, and other methods for choosing the members are proposed ([discussion](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1673))

Comment: As far as I know, yes, transactions could always have more than one real input.